# Conditionally reload component based on previous route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Perhaps someone can help me with a React Native issue I’m having with `react-navigation` (2.0.4). I have a page (Page C - RouteShowScreen) that I want to conditionally reload, depending on whether or it was navigated to from Page A (RoutePrepareScreen) or Page X (Any other page navigating to Page C), and I just can’t seem to get the lifecyle methods correct. To be clear, I want the page to reload if it is navigated to from Page A (RoutePrepareScreen), but not if it is navigated to from any other screen.  I tried using the `willFocus` listener, but then Page C reloads regardless of whether it was navigated to from Page A or Page B.

**RoutePrepareScreen**

```
...

this.props.navigation.navigate("RouteShow", {
  currentLat: latitude,
  currentLng: longitude,
  destinationAddress: this.state.destinationAddress,
  currentAddress: this.formatCurrentAddress(),
  destinationLat,
  destinationLng,
  speed,
  hoursUntilBreak,
  estimatedShiftLength});
}

...
```

**RouteShowScreen**

```
/** This caused the page to reload, regardless of how it was navigated to **/

willFocus = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'willFocus',
  () => {
    this.handleRouteLoad();
  }
);

/** I also tried using componentWillReceiveProps and adding an additional "reload" navigation parameter, but this threw the
app into an infinite loop **/

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.navigation.state.params.reload) {
    this.handleRouteLoad();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I was able to get this to work by resetting the navigation stack when navigating from within `RoutePrepareScreen` - like this:

```
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName: "RouteShow",
          params: {
            currentLat: latitude,
            currentLng: longitude,
            destinationAddress: this.state.destinationAddress,
            currentAddress: this.formatCurrentAddress(),
            destinationLat,
            destinationLng,
            speed,
            hoursUntilBreak,
            estimatedShiftLength,
          }
        })
      ],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

However, this feels a little dirty to me (and might be untenable if the use case cannot handle a full reset of the navigation stack). I'd be curious to see another solution!